# PyTorch CNN model's inference performance depends on batch size

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have a CNN model which is basically just VGG16. I train it with my own data then using the model to infer the same dataset as a part of the model evaluation. The code is roughly as follows:

```
batch_size = 16
misclassified_count = 0
data_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

with torch.no_grad():
    # Loop through the images in batches
    for batch_idx, (images, y_trues) in enumerate(data_loader):

        images = images.to(device)

        output = vgg6(images)
        _, predicted = torch.max(output, dim=1)

        for i, pred_label in enumerate(predicted):
            y_true = y_trues[i].item()
            pred_label = pred_label.item()

            if pred_label == y_true:
                continue

            misclassified_count += 1

print(f'{misclassified_count} misclassified samples found')
```

The problem is, as I increase the `batch_size`, the misclassified samples will decrease:

```
batch_size=1, 2872 misclassified samples found
batch_size=2, 2133 misclassified samples found
batch_size=4, 1637 misclassified samples found
batch_size=8, 1364 misclassified samples found
batch_size=16, 1097 misclassified samples found
```

Any thoughts? Is there any flaw in my code?

Comment: Maybe, `vgg6` is not in eval mode by any chance ? Since I do not see the instantiation and the part prior I'm not sure. However, when you do inference only, you should set your model in eval mode `model.eval()`. Some components behave differently between training and inference. Plus, torch.no_grad() and model.eval() do not function in the exact same way. In short, for evaluation or inference you should use both of them.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is the use of `_, predicted = torch.max(output, dim=1)` why not argmax ? I didn't really get what you are trying to do with the `max` function.

Comment: @null the model is instantiated by `vgg16 = model.VGG16()` and then weighted are loaded by, `v16mm.load_state_dict(model_path)`, I didnt call `vgg16.eval()`. Is the model always in `train()` mode if I didnt call `eval()`?

Comment: @null on `torch.max(output, dim=1)`, is the result the same as `argmax()`? I get the initial version from somewhere, (perhaps from ChatGPT?) and it just works, is `argmax()` only more “intuitive” or more "dedicated" to this purpose?

Comment: It is a terrible idea to use ChatGPT for this, as you see it told you to use max, which is incorrect, you have to use argmax. They give you completely different concepts.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I cant really agree with this tho. At least ChatGPT's reply as toxic as SO.

Comment: @D.J.Elkind And yet ChatGPT's answer was incorrect and here you are asking us about it, people already answered your question and pointed out the two mistakes in your code (not using argmax and not using eval()).

Comment: Without GPT I cant even come up with the first version of the code and you see? my question gets downvoted. GPT never downvotes my question anyway

Comment: No but ChatGPT gives you wrong answers, and then you waste your time and other people's time by asking about their answer. You did not properly reply to the issues we pointed here (using argmax and eval). And people did program before ChatGPT existed, there is no strong reason to use it, learning on your own is much better, the internet is full of tutorials on PyTorch and other DL libraries.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy if you think I waste your time, feel free to downvote me and just shut up.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set your model into `eval` mode by calling `vgg6.eval()`. In eval mode the behavior of layer changes. [BatchNorm](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BatchNorm2d.html) layer will use the running mean and variance which were estimated during the training, instead of using the current minibatch to calculate the mean and variance.

The fact that you get better results for bigger batch sizes strongly points to the missing `eval` mode. Since with a bigger minibatch the mean and variance calculated are closer to the ones during training probably. Since calculating them over more data is generally closer to the overall mean and variance of all data.

Also dropout layers behave differently in train and eval mode. In train it randomly drops inputs, where in eval it just scales them with the droput probability. So having it in train when you do eval will just lead to more variance in your output but it not based on batch size.

Edit to answer a follow up question in the comments

> But I have a follow-up question: it is expected that the exact number of misclassified samples is different? I get something like 30, 32, 27, 28 misclassified samples if I run the inference a few times, using exactly the same model?

Executing a model is on default at least partly non deterministic. CUDA and CUDNN both use nondeterministic algorithms so each run the output can be slightly different. Depending on how sensitive a given model is to small variations of the output this might lead to small variations in an overall evaluation. Mainly samples that are on the edge of being correct or false can "flip" over to the other case. So you might get some samples wrong or right seemingly randomly for the worst case.

Variations like 28-32 misclassified samples (so a deviation of 4) are to be expected when it seems like your total count of samples are in the thousands or even tens of thousands.

Also other things like pre and postprocessing can be nondeterministic, but in your case it seems like you input just images and don't seem to have any complicated pre processing or post processing, which might introduce non deterministic behavior.

If you want determinism you can always try to follow this [page](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html). You basically fix all seeds there are, set some variables and so on. But note that some CUDA and CUDNN algorithms are inherently nondeterministic and can't be run in a deterministic way, but if this is the case you will get very clear error, when trying to use the deterministic flag.

Making it deterministic might increase the overall runtime of the model and you also might make it deterministic in a way where it is worse on average. So be careful with it and only do it if you really need deterministic behavior. Normally one can live with these small variations.

Comment: This does appear to solve the issue and the number of misclassified samples decreases quite a lot (which is something I expect). But I have a follow-up question: it is expected that the exact number of misclassified samples is different? I get something like 30, 32, 27, 28 misclassified samples if I run the inference a few times, using exactly the same model?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind I updated my answer to include your follow up question.